# Opening HTML pages from Raw storage along with referenced contents

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

I have made a list view which opens a website stored in the apps raw data folder according to which button is pressed. This works fine, the problem is none of the assets are loading.

The files are stored like this:

```
Raw 
   Webpage.html
   WebPageFolder
       Webpage.css
       image_1.png
```

The images are currently referenced from inside the html page like this:

```
<img src="WebPageFolder/image_1.png" alt="" style="height: 180px; left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px; width: 257px; " />
```

Is there anyway of fixing this without having to specify the file locations using "file:///android_res/raw" inside the html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The files are stored like this

That is not possible in raw resources, as you cannot have subdirectories in resource directories. It is possible via `assets/`. I **strongly** encourage you to move your files into `assets/`, then use a `file:///android_asset/` URL to load the content into your `WebView`.